# access violation at address 004EAE10 in module 'project.exe' write of address 00000004'

Tags: delphi

I 've a problem in my project. it is when I click button close application and this code is

```
procedure Tflogin.btnKeluarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  application.Terminate;
end;
```

will show a meg box error " access violation at address 004EAE10 in module 'project.exe' write of address 00000004'" how to fix it ?

this is code in my project dpr 
program NEW_SPJK;

```
uses
  Forms,
  Controls,
  login in 'login.pas' {flogin},
  udm in 'header\udm.pas' {dm: TDataModule},
  umenu in 'header\umenu.pas' {fmenu},
  urelasi in 'header\urelasi.pas' {frelasi},
  ubagian in 'header\ubagian.pas' {fbagian},
  umetode in 'header\umetode.pas' {fmetode},
  utambahhasil in 'header\utambahhasil.pas' {ftambahhasil},
  utambahtanya in 'header\utambahtanya.pas' {ftambahtanya},
  udaftar in 'header\udaftar.pas' {fdaftar},
  ubiodata in 'header\ubiodata.pas' {fbiodata},
  ujawab in 'header\ujawab.pas' {Form2},
  uhasil in 'header\uhasil.pas' {fhasil},
  uinformasi in 'header\uinformasi.pas' {fdaftarsiswa},
  uabout in 'header\uabout.pas' {ftentang},
  upilihbagiaan in 'header\upilihbagiaan.pas' {fproses},
  umemo in 'header\umemo.pas' {fmemo};



{$R *.res}
var LoginOK: Boolean;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(Tdm, dm);
  Application.CreateForm(Tfmenu, fmenu);
  Application.CreateForm(Tflogin, flogin);
  Application.CreateForm(Tfproses, fproses);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.CreateForm(Tfhasil, fhasil);
  Application.CreateForm(Tfbiodata, fbiodata);
  with Tflogin.Create(nil) do begin
    LoginOK:=(ShowModal=mrOK);
    Application.CreateForm(Tfmenu, fmenu);
    Free;
  end;
  if not LoginOK then Halt;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using in your dpr file.

Comment: Is the `Tflogin` form created by your main form?  Are you trying to terminate the application from a popup modal window?  It would help to see the code you use to display the login dialog.

Comment: You are accessing a `nil` pointer. We cannot see enough code. Please show SSCCE.

Comment: i use fmenu for main form... this is my code in project dpr

Comment: i use fmenu for main form... this is my code in project dpr

    begin
        LoginOK:=(ShowModal=mrOK);
        Application.CreateForm(Tfmenu, fmenu);
        Free;
      end;
      if not LoginOK then Halt;
 Application.Run;
end.

Comment: That's not the real code. Don't type it in. Paste it. Please edit the question to add code. It won't work in comments. If you make a good question we can reopen it to answer you.

Comment: okay mr david sorry i dont undarstand about this make a post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious mistake in the code that you have shown is that you do this twice:

```
Application.CreateForm(Tfmenu, fmenu);
```

I believe you meant to do that once only.

As general advice, there's only ever need to call `Application.CreateForm` once and that's to create the main form. The rest of the time you can call the form's constructor. And I also suggest that you might benefit from not using global variables and auto-created forms. It's better practice to create form's when you need them, and destroy them when they are closed.